# VBA Syntax error on creating table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting syntax error when trying to create simple table and i don't know why. It works when i write `.name` after it and it also works when i write only `ws.ListObjects.Add`. So can somebody please explain what is the correct syntax?
Thank you.

```
Sub CreateTable()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks("?????")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("owssvr-úpravené")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    rng.Find(What:="Next_Review_Date", LookAt:=xlWhole).Name = "Next_Review_Date"
    With ws.Range("Next_Review_Date").Offset(0, 1)
         .EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
         .EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
         .EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With

    With ws.Range("Next_Review_Date")
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = "Rozdiel dátumov"
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = "Overdue"
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = "Review year"
    End With

    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried [Googling the correct syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobjects-add-method-excel)?  (It would have taken less time than typing the question!)

Comment: @ashleedawg While looking into the docs is always a good idea, I think it is not about syntax of this specific function but more a thing about when do you use brackets and when not. Therefore I think your link is not helping at *this* question.

Comment: @ashleedawg Yeah i was on that site but like Peh mentioned it was about that brackets and i wanted to olso know why it ist working like that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - The question clearly says `what is the correct syntax?` ...so that's what I posted a link to.

Comment: @ashleedawg  i wrote `wthat is the correct syntax` because VBA was marking it red like it was syntax problem so i thought i was wrting it in bad syntax. I visited that site but the brackets were the problem. I'm novice in VBA and sorry if you were annoyed with my question.

Comment: @ashleedawg yes and the docs show it *with brackets* and setting the result into a variable, but the docs don't show how the correct syntax is if you don't want to set the result into a variable, that's what I mean. It's just hard for a beginner to find out what gone wrong here by just reading that docs. I think that this is not the lazyness of the OP but more being a beginner. I think the question was quite OK to ask here. I mean it is not very logical of VBA that you have to omit the brackets, most other languages would keep the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets from

```
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
```

**Why?**
If you call a procedure/function without returning something into a variable then **use no brackets**:

```
ws.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes
```

if you return something **use brackets**:

```
MyVariable = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
```

This is valid for all other functions/procedures too.

Comment: Thank you very much